# Pover Pivot/ Power Query filter issue

Tags: excel, pivot

This is possibly a newbie question.
I have done a lot of Excel reporting with VBA and SQL statements in the past, but wanted to give Power Query/Power Pivot a try. Took an online class and everything looks easy until you try it yourself (as usual).

Here is my easy problem:

I want to do a training report for employees in different locations (stores).
As shown below I have a "location table" with Store IDs, an "employee table" with Employee ID and store_ID (linked in the data model), and a "training table" with Employee ID and class types.
What I want to see is a list of (filtered) locations, their employees and the classes taken...

[image: Table Layout]

The problem starts with the Employee pivot already,

This should show me the employees of the selected location: (But it shows all employees from all locations, despite of the set filter "2360").

[image: Pivot 1]

Playing around I found it will filter correctly for names when I add a "Count of" into the Calculations field... What the hell?

This now will give me the correct employees per store but now the classes 
are not correct and it looks like everybody took all classes. (Which is not true):

[image]

All tables are clean and have no duplicates or other issues.
(The class table obviously has multiple entries for students, but 
not for classes).

I had planned to also have a filter for the time-frame of classes taken,
but at this time I am humbled...

Thank you for any advice or pointer!!!

The data model arrows are as seen on the screen shots, "Field" is the "Class_type" column in the class table.  ("field training" or "in-house").
(The table on the right below without header is the class table).

[image: first connection]

[image: connection to class table]

Comment: What is that column "Field" in your pivot table? That looks weird. Can you show a screenshot of your data model with the connection arrows?

Comment: Hi TeylynI have added the information above.